# Function inside functional component in React

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component

I am trying to execute a function inside functional component in React. My code is like below

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';


function App() {

  function checkvalue(checkboxElem) {
    if (checkboxElem.checked) {
      alert("hi");
    } else {
      alert("bye");
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
        <div><input type="checkbox" onchange="checkvalue(this)"/>Bracelets</div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

But the function is not working.

Answer (score 2):

The JSX syntax i a bit different if you come from the world of Angular.

You need to have curly braces for any assigning of value/function to element property:

```js
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  function checkvalue(checkboxElem) {
    if (checkboxElem.checked) {
      alert('hi');
    } else {
      alert('bye');
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" onChange={checkvalue} /> {/* <----- HERE */}
        Bracelets
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

Handling events with React elements is very similar to handling events on DOM elements. There are some syntax differences:

For example, the HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" onchange="checkvalue(this)"/>
```

is slightly different in React:

```
<input type="checkbox" onChange={checkvalue}/>
```

Comment: Thanks @Abhijeet Abnave. I am getting error `Error: Expected `onChange` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `string` type.`

Comment: `onChange={checkvalue(this)}` will execute the function before waiting for a `change` to happen. `onChange={(e) => checkvalue(e.target)}` will be more accurate

Comment: @abuabu you need to use onChange={(e) => checkvalue(e.target)} you might have been passing string in onChange like onChange={"checkvalue()"} this is wrong

Comment: Thanks @SinanYaman. Your solution is working.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues within your code.

You're passing the onChange prop incorrectly. Right now, you're passing it as a string and passing it to the incorrect prop

```
<... onchange="checkvalue(this)" ... />
```

The correct way to pass a non-string value (including interpolated strings) is to wrap it around curly braces `{}`. The correct prop to pass the change callback to is `onChange`.

```
<... onChange={checkvalue(this)} ... />
```

Comment: `onChange={checkvalue(this)}` will execute the function immediately during render. You might want to change that into `onChange={(e) => checkvalue(e.target)}`

Answer (score 0):

change

```
<input type="checkbox" onchange="checkvalue(this)"/>
```

to

```
<input type="checkbox" onChange={checkValue}/>
```

and

```
  function checkValue(event) {
    if (event.target.checked) {
      alert("hi");
    } else {
      alert("bye");
    }
  }
```